# SQLAchemy and Django

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

Is there a some way to do the same thing like prefetch_related in DjangoORM in SQLAlchemy?

I have models like this:

```
class User(...):
    regions  = models.ManyToMany(Region)
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Region(...): 
    title = models.CharField(...)
```

And I have the same classes for sql alchemy.

And I want to rewrite the code in sql alchemy:

```
name = 'Lucas'
users = User.objects.filter(name=name).prefetch_related('regions')
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html

Answer (score 1):

not without significant difficulty.  the default django ORM is very tightly integrated and replacing it with SQLAlchemy is a non-trivial task.

https://github.com/Deepwalker/aldjemy suggests it can help with this.

Comment: Aldjemy is very good - super easy to get working seems well maintained.  A newer project https://github.com/shosca/django-sorcery also exists, which does most of django and has an in-progress version of django-admin as well (at the time of writing) - initial screenshots look promising.  A django-rest-sqlalchemy edition also exists alongside django-sorcery